# Send automated emails of PowerBI report to individual people or a mailing list

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have created a PowerBI report and set it to refresh the data sources everyday.
**I want to send emails with the link of the report every week automatically** to select people/mailing list. Emails need not be sent from my email, i just need to share the report.

I saw that there are subscriptions on powerbi, **can I subscribe other people or a mailing list to my report?**

I saw that a other party tool powerbi robots can do this, is it possible to do this without any otherparty tools.

Comment: [Subscribe others to your reports and dashboards in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-report-subscribe)

Comment: if i select a page and add subscription and check the option of : Also include-"Access to this report" will other be able to access the full report?

Comment: Yes, but note that all recipients needs Pro license